# c# find char and get the line no of the result

Tags: c#

I need a help in getting the line no of a string where we found a particular string.
Example : I have file .txt with this string

hello

thanks;;

build;;;

but;;;;;

I want to get the line no of the ';' less than 3
So that I can remove the '\n' and that the result must be written to file like

hello

thanks;;build;;;

but;;;;;

I think I'm clear plzz help me out. Actually I had tried spilt but I can't replace '\n' and write it back to the file. It is only showing the line no.

Comment: Are ';' always at the end of line?

Comment: Replace(new string[]{enviroment.newline},"");

Comment: Thanks for your reply for @doctor no actually as I said I want to find the no of occurrences I mean "if count(;) < 3 then"

Comment: Hello @ThomasAndreèLian actually my main problem is how to find that in which line I should use this function of replace... I want to find in which line is count of ; is < than 3

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var lines = new List<string>();
// read lines from file to lines list

var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

foreach(var line in lines)
{        
    stringBuilder.Append(line);

    var semicolonCount = line.Count(x => x == ';');   //To Count the char
    if(semicolonCount == 0 || semicolonCount > 2)     //To state the occurrence
    {
        stringBuilder.Append(Environment.NewLine);
    }
}

var resultText = stringBuilder.ToString();
// write this into the file
```

Comment: Hello @MaKCbIMKo thanks for your reply but there is a problem with the code. in 'if' you have given

 line = line.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, string.Empty);

but it showing a error

Error CS1656 "Cannot assign to 'line' because it is a 'foreach iteration variable' "

if I remove line then it is removing all the line breaks from the file

Comment: Now the error is fixed but it is replace all the line breaks in the file. It is not replacing that single line.

Comment: Thx mate it worked............ Really thx I was looking for this since 4 hrs.... But a small edit. It should be <2

Comment: I thought you need to use 'new line' if there are 3 or more semicolons (it means >2). it means that if there 1 or 2 semicolons it will not use (remove) 'new line'.

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] lines = theText.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
string[] resultLines = lines.Where(l => l.Contains(";;;")).ToArray();
```

It's also possible to make this using [Regular Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Try Regex:

```
string text = File.ReadAllText("test.txt");

string pattern = @"(?<!;)(;;)(?:\r\n)+";

string result = Regex.Replace(text, pattern, m => m.Groups[1].Value);
```